# Store AJAX parameters in URL (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I was already able to replace the posts using AJAX upon submitting the form. The problem though, is that the URL is not updating to include the params I added.

When I click on Submit, the values are passed to the controller. I can call `params[:tags]` and it will return the IDs. However, the URL is still `localhost:3000/posts/:id` and it didn't include the tag_ids.

Here are the affected files:

`posts_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @posts = get_posts

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end
```

`posts/show.html.haml`:

```
#posts
  = render "posts", { posts: posts }

= form_tag url_for(:only_path => false), method: :get, remote: true, id: "posts-form" do
 
  @tags.each do |tag|
    = check_box_tag "tags[]", tag[:id]
    = tag[:name]

  = submit_tag "Filter"
```

`posts/show.js.erb`:

```
$('#posts').html("<%= j (render 'posts', posts: @posts) %>")
```

Comment: An AJAX call (``remote: true``) won't change the page URL.

Comment: @rmlockerd got this, would you know of alternatives on how to do this?

Comment: No, sorry. The primary purpose of AJAX is to dynamically update content of an existing page _without_ formally changing or updating the location. If you want to include the filter tags in a URL (for bookmarking, for example), maybe a regular HTTP POST would work better for you?